# Perl regexp for multiple possibilities

Tags: regex, perl

Imagine you have following lines to parse:

```
2061;2014-XXX-10;12345;12345;2014-XXX-10;1;MACRO;ID;;3060;204;08;;;;;;1;;;
2061;YYY016582;2099130;11;1658-YYY 20;1;MACRO;ID;64543;;204;08;20010314;;20010314;60454;AA;1;;;
2061;ZZZ010421;38571;38571;1042-ZZZ-30;3;MACRO;ID;;6010;204;08;200010904;;200010904;22347;AB;2;;;
```

how should my regexp look to match the fields `2014-XXX-10`, `YYY016582`, and `ZZZ010421`? One field, three different formats

I tried `(xxx)|(bbb)|(ccc)` thing, but no success.

To explain litle bit more. I'm reading the lines from file and will import the values separated by semicolons `;` into MySQL. So I need to store all fields to a variable. I don't want to use split here. The values bolded are just example, it can be different, but always one of three formats `YYY\d{6}`, `ZZZ\d{6}`, or `\d{4}-XXX-\d`.

Comment: split according to `;` and then print the second column.4

Comment: What about https://regex101.com/r/nO4sU8/2?

Comment: don't really want to use split here. Just need to match all possibilities of that string

Comment: Your requirement is unclear. Do you want to find all occurrences of those three *literal strings*, or is there some pattern that we should have grasped? I can't spot a pattern that matches those three and not, say, `1042-ZZZ-30`

Comment: hope I clarified the question little bit

Comment: Please explain why you don't want to use `split`?

Comment: somehow I feel, that with split I have no control whats coming in. With regexp I will be notified if data in the file will be of different format. Or do I see it wrong ?

Comment: You can use both - split AND regex to filter out what you actually want.

Comment: @taiko: I think you have it wrong. Unless you have no confidence in the incoming data — say it's been typed in by hand or something — then you can trust it to have the semicolons in the right place. In any case, what happens if your data doesn't match your regex? Do you `die`? Do you issue a warning and carry on? Or do you just ignore the data silently? See another update to my solution for an example

Comment: @RahulDesai: I'm pretty sure the OP doesn't need to do any filtering, and just needs to `split /;/`, but feels they need to write a pattern to *verify* every field in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to match any of those three strings, then you can write

```
/(?<![0-9A-Z\-])(2014-XXX-10|YYY016582|ZZZ010421)(?![0-9A-Z\-])/
```

The negative look-ahead and look-behind are there to make sure you don't match part of a longer field that just happens to contain one of those values

---

**Update**

If you want to match anything that looks like either `9999-AAA-99` or `AAA999999` then it should be

```
/ (?<![0-9A-Z\-]) ( \d{4}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2} | [A-Z]{3}\d{6} ) (?![0-9A-Z\-]) /x
```

---

**Update**

If you would use `split` then it would be much simpler. Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while ( <DATA> ) {
  chomp;
  my @matches = grep /^ (?: YYY\d{6} | ZZZ\d{6} | \d{4}-XXX-\d{2} ) $/x, split /;/;
  say "@matches";
}


__DATA__
2061;2014-XXX-10;51636;51636;2014-XXX-10;1;MACRO;ID;;3060;204;08;;;;;;1;;;2061;YYY016582;2099130;11;1658-YYY-20;1;MACRO;ID;64501;;204;08;20010314;;20010314;60454;AA;1;;;2061;ZZZ010421;38571;38571;1042-ZZZ-30;3;MACRO;ID;;6010;204;08;200010904;;200010904;22347;AB;2;;;
```

**output**

```
2014-XXX-10 2014-XXX-10 YYY016582 ZZZ010421
```

---

**Update**

Unless you have no confidence in your data and need to handle malformed records then I think you just need to do a simple `split` on the records. Like this.

It's hard to illustrate. This code just prints the fields in the data surrounded by square brackets, and preceded by the number of fields found. You would want to write the information to your database instead of printing it

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while ( <DATA> ) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /;/;
  printf "%d: %s\n", scalar @fields, join(' ', map "[$_]", @fields);
}


__DATA__
2061;2014-XXX-10;12345;12345;2014-XXX-10;1;MACRO;ID;;3060;204;08;;;;;;1;;;
2061;YYY016582;2099130;11;1658-YYY 20;1;MACRO;ID;64543;;204;08;20010314;;20010314;60454;AA;1;;;
2061;ZZZ010421;38571;38571;1042-ZZZ-30;3;MACRO;ID;;6010;204;08;200010904;;200010904;22347;AB;2;;;
```

**output**

```
18: [2061] [2014-XXX-10] [12345] [12345] [2014-XXX-10] [1] [MACRO] [ID] [] [3060] [204] [08] [] [] [] [] [] [1]
18: [2061] [YYY016582] [2099130] [11] [1658-YYY 20] [1] [MACRO] [ID] [64543] [] [204] [08] [20010314] [] [20010314] [60454] [AA] [1]
18: [2061] [ZZZ010421] [38571] [38571] [1042-ZZZ-30] [3] [MACRO] [ID] [] [6010] [204] [08] [200010904] [] [200010904] [22347] [AB] [2]
```

Comment: I made some progress using you regexp. Do mind to explain to me what " (?<![0-9A-Z\-]) " does at the beginning and at the end of the regexp?

Comment: @taiko: That's the negative lookahead and look-behinds that I mentioned. If you would use `split` then they would be unnecessary

Comment: thanx a lot. Almost finished my regexp. You helped me a lot. Sorry for being unclear in the beginning.

Comment: @taiko: I've added an example that uses `split`, which I would have thought was ideal for your purpose

Comment: sorry for silly question, but I'm not sure if you relaized, that my data is in lines. So I need to parse one line, store fields separated  by ";" in regex groups and then assign stored values to variables, like  my $a = $1; my $b = $2; etc. The other fields are easy to match, because the keep their format along all lines, only field 2 of the line can have three differemnt formats

Comment: @taiko: Yes, my sample code has the single line of data that you showed in `@matches`. If all you really need is to collect the semicolon-separated fields then all you need is `while (<FH>) { chomp; my @fields = split /;/; ...}` and use the contents of `@fields` to write to the database. There is no need to match the individual fields at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could do matching and replacing.

```
$ perl -pe 's/^[^;]*;([^;]*);.*/\1/' file
2014-XXX-10
YYY016582
ZZZ010421
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this RegEx: `/(\d{4}-)?[A-Z]+-?\d+/g`

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/tV5eA9/3)

**Explanation:**

[image]

---

**EDIT:** In response to the updated question, you can use the following regex:

```
/(Y{3}\d{6})|(Z{3}\d{6})|(\d{4}-X{3}-\d+)/g
```

[Demo & Explanation](https://www.regex101.com/r/tV5eA9/4)

Comment: it wasn't me, I clicked "vote up", but -1 appeared. Your solution looks good to me, but I need to store all fields separated by ";" in variables.                       Something like /^(\d{1,})\;( some magic rexexp )\;(\d{1,})\;(\d{1,}) etc etc ?/

Comment: @taiko Do you need to store all fields separated by `;` in variables AND match that regex?

Comment: That will match fields in the example data other than the highlighted ones. You may as well write `/[^;]+/`

Comment: @taiko Can you please answer Borodin's comment to your question?

Comment: @taiko Please checkout the EDIT in my answer above with the working RegEx and demo of the same.

Comment: @Rahul yes, your regexp does the trick as well, thank you very much. Unfortunately "vote up" still brings -1 for me :(

Comment: @taiko To learn how to upvote, please see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) (click the arrow/triangle pointing upward and is above `0`). If you found this answer good enough, you can also accept it.

Comment: :) ; I know how to up vote, I voted for Borodin. Just it doesn't work if I want up vote your answer

Comment: @taiko Not sure why that is happening. Also, I just realized that you dont have a good track of accepting answers, do you?